# How do I compute maximum/minimum of 8 different float values

Tags: c, floating-point, comparison

I need to find maximum and minimum of 8 float values I get. I did as follows. But float comparisons are going awry as warned by any good C book!
How do I compute the max and min in a accurate way.

```
main()
{
    float mx,mx1,mx2,mx3,mx4,mn,mn1,mn2,mn3,mn4,tm1,tm2;

    mx1 = mymax(2.1,2.01); //this returns 2.09999 instead of 2.1 because a is passed as 2.09999.
    mx2 = mymax(-3.5,7.000001);
    mx3 = mymax(7,5);
    mx4 = mymax(7.0000011,0); //this returns incorrectly- 7.000001
    tm1 = mymax(mx1,mx2);
    tm2 = mymax(mx3,mx4);
    mx = mymax(tm1,tm2);

    mn1 = mymin(2.1,2.01);
    mn2 = mymin(-3.5,7.000001);
    mn3 = mymin(7,5);
    mn4 = mymin(7.0000011,0);
    tm1 = mymin(mx1,mx2);
    tm2 = mymin(mx3,mx4);
    mn = mymin(tm1,tm2);


    printf("Max is %f, Min is %f \n",mx,mn);

    getch();
}

float mymax(float a,float b)
{
    if(a >= b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return b;
    }
}

float mymin(float a,float b)
{
    if(a <= b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

How can I do exact comparisons of these floats? This is all C code.

thank you.

-AD.

Comment: As you state, precision of the `float` data type isn't sufficient for what you're attempting to do here. As it goes, IEEE754 `float` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary32 - only has `1+8+23` bits for sign/exponent/mantissa and rounding errors become very visible at six decimal digits already.  Is there a specific reason why you cannot use `double`, and/or an arbitrary-precision math library like GMP ?

Comment: Using `double` instead of `float` will not solve the problem of not being able to represent exactly 2.1

Comment: Exactly, using double does not help in this case.

Comment: That's all true - but within the (here used) precision of seven decimal digits `double` is precise enough. You can of course trivially construct the same case with `double` just using a longer fractional part; in the end, decimal floating point numbers of limited precision cannot be loslessly mapped to binary floating point - some decimal fractions form infinite series in binary. As indicated, if you require this sort of precision, interval math libraries or arbitrary precision (fractional numbers) libraries might be a good idea to look at.

Comment: @goldenmean @Didier: actually, the precision of the float type is the real issue in this case, not the representation of decimals.

Comment: @goldenmean -- If you only want to find the maximum, as your question indicates, then there isn't a problem is there? You get told which number was the biggest and which is the smallest by your test code.What you do not get is absolute precision. Now that may or may not be a problem for you. But it is a different question.

Comment: @AAT: Thanks. I got what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* doing exact comparison of these floats. The problem (with your example code at least) is that `float` simply does not have enough digits of precision to represent the values of your literals sufficiently. **`7.000001` and `7.0000011` simply are so close together that the mantissa of a 32 bit `float` cannot represent them differently.**

But the example seems artificial. What is the real problem you're trying to solve? What values will you actually be working with? Or is this just an academic exercise?

The best solution depends on the answer to that. If your actual values just require somewhat more more precision than `float` can provide, use `double`. If you need exact representation of decimal digits, use a decimal type library. If you want to improve your understanding of how floating point values work, read [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: @Agreed this is a cooked up example. But my actual values of floats are the result of a previous floating point division of a floating point difference of two floats.

Comment: @goldenmean: So where is the actual problem? That there can in some rare cases be results that just happen to be so close together that the limited precision of floating-point values does not represent them in the same order as a perfectly accuarate data type would? Is your input data really *that* accurate to begin with?

Comment: @Michael: I see. Thanks for helping. When i looks carefully at my floating pt. data, it so happens that even if in some cases when a certain data point was really so accurate that it was not representable by the float pt nos, the floating pt. arithmetic which happens before this comparison(max/min computation) has already lost that precision and the input to this max/min computation is a aprroximation. So i dont need to worry about that part i guess. Just give max/min of whatever it gets as input.

Comment: Another good link is "What Every Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" (http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Bart: which was the inspiration to the site I linked to and is of course listed there as "further reading".

Comment: @Michael: You caught me in not checking out the link you provided :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do exact comparison of floats. Either directly as floats, or by casting them to int with the same bit representation.

```
float a = 1.0f;
float b = 2.0f;
int &ia = *(int *)(&a);
int &ib = *(int *)(&b);

/* you can compare a and b, or ia and ib, the results will be the same,
   whatever the values of the floats are.
   Floats are ordered the correct way when its bits are considered as int
   and thus can be compared (provided that float and int both are 32 bits).
 */
```

But you will *never* be able to represent exactly 2.1 as a float.

Your problem is not a problem of comparison, it is a problem of representation of a value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd claim that these comparisons are actually exact, since no value is altered.

The problem is that many float literals can't be represented exactly by IEEE-754 floating point numbers. So for example 2.1.

If you need an exact representation of base 10 pointed numbers you could - for example - write your own fixed point BCD arithmetic.

Concerning finding min and max at the same time:

A way that needs less comparisons is for each index pair (2*i, 2*i+1) first finding the minimum (n/2 comparisons)

Then find the minimum of the minima ((n-1)/2 comparisons) and the maximum of the maxima ((n-1)/2 comparisons).

So we get (3*n-2)/2 comparisons instead of (2*n-2)/2 when finding the minimum and maximum separated.

Answer (score 0):

The `<` and `>` comparison always works correct with floats or doubles. Only the `==` comparison has problems, therefore you are advised to use epsilon.

So your method of calculating min, max has no issue. Note that if you use float, you should use the notation `2.1f` instead of `2.1`. Just a note.

Comment: It's not the == comparison itself that has problems either, it's the expectation its use is usually based on, that mathematically equivalent operations will produce identical float values.

Comment: Yes, my answer lacks some detail in that sense.